# Big Cartel Luna Theme: Making the Products Page the Home Page

Tags: bigcartel

Currently using big cartel Luna theme for a pop up shop. How do I remove the home page and just use the products page as the landing page? I’ve seen it done but no idea how!

Thank you! Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

So long as you are not using the free plan, you can copy the default code from the product page and replace the home page custom code with it.